# Find a $\delta_\epsilon$ for symmetrical or asymmetrical interval for a simple limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

We consider the following limit 
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{x}=\frac 12$$

and we will verify from the definition of limit that:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \ \delta_{\epsilon}>0: \Biggl|\frac{1}{x}-\frac 12\Biggr|<\epsilon, x\in\mathbb R, x\neq 2, |x-2|<\delta.$$
Now, considering that $x\to 2$, obviously the denominator is always positive and therefore
$$\Biggl|\frac{2-x}{2x}\Biggr|=\frac{|2-x|}{|2x|}<\epsilon \Longrightarrow |2-x|<\epsilon$$
and if I take $\delta_\epsilon=\epsilon$ I have a complete open circle of $2$. We suppose that I use another strategy, using the systeme made that two inequalities

$$-\epsilon <\frac{2-x}{2x} < \epsilon$$
If I solve it I will try an asymmetrical round circular (open) of $2$ of the type (I not sure if is true the (1) - I'm using my memory)

$$2\in \left]\frac{2}{1+2\epsilon};\frac{2}{1-2\epsilon}\right[ \tag{1}$$

If I wanted to find a open circumference that is circular and symmetrical, I have thought to put into a system a circumference $\mathcal C$ that it has the center in $(2,0)$ and radius $2/1+2\epsilon$ and intersect this circumference $\mathcal C$ with the $x-$axis. I think that the point of intersection with the $x-$axis is less than $2/1-2\epsilon$.

What do I take for $\delta_\epsilon$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow this approach, you can subtract $2$ from $\frac{2}{1+2\epsilon}<x<\frac{2}{1-2\epsilon}$, which would give you $\frac{-4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}<x-2<\frac{4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon} \Rightarrow |x-2|<\frac{4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}$, so you know what $\delta$ to choose. There is a caveat here that this only works for $1-2\epsilon>0$ but it's not that hard a problem to deal with this.

There's also a standard approach to these $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs, which is that you find an upper bound for all factors other than $|x-2|$ (in this case). For instance, if $|x-2|<1$ (remember you can take $x$ as close to $2$ as you want), then $1<x<3 \Rightarrow |x|>1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|2x|}<\frac12$, so $\frac{|2-x|}{|2x|}=\frac{|x-2|}{|2x|}<\frac{|x-2|}{2}$ and to ensure this is less than $\epsilon$, you need to have $|x-2|<2\epsilon$. So we choose $\delta=\min(1,2\epsilon)$, which is just a shorthand for saying we want both $|x-2|<1$ and $|x-2|<2\epsilon$ to be true.

Comment: Thank you very much for you collaboration and for your answer. But it is not wrong, for my opinion if I ignore the denominator since $x$ tends to $2>0$ and I take as $\delta_\epsilon=\epsilon<2\epsilon$. Is it not true? Addendum: $\frac{-4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}\neq \frac{4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon}$ (see the denominator) and I not can have $|x-2|<\frac{4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Sebastiano I didn't mean that your idea is wrong. It's just a matter of writing a rigorous proof. Choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ by itself is not enough. You can add *using words* that because $x\to 2$, we can make $x$ very close to $2$ and that has certain implications. Also, $\frac{4\epsilon}{1+2\epsilon}<\frac{4\epsilon}{1-2\epsilon}$ (provided $1-2\epsilon>0$), so we are OK there.

Comment: Thank you very much but I necessary must to choose the way for simple for my students. For this reason I have put this question. However, with lot of sincerity, I have given to you +1 :-) and others.